# Plain text to Hexadecimal manually

Tags: hex, data-conversion, plaintext

How to **manually** convert a  plain text to hexadecimal ?
Eg Hexadecimal form of `Hello`

P.S I do not need code but the manual way to convert.

Comment: Do you mean Unicode/ASCII values of H, e, l, l, and o?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

--Convert the string to its ASCII form
--Convert ASCII(decimal) to Hex

Eg  Hello in ASCII is 
    H is 72 ,e is 101, l is 108 , o is 111
    And the Hex value of
    72 is 48
    101 is 65
    108 is 6c
    111 is 6f
So the Hex representation of `Hello` is `48656c6c6f`

Answer (score 0):

For example  Hello present in text take that string character-wise, where H=72(int value)  to HEXADECIMAL

DIVISION=   72 / 16      RESULT = 4 REMAINDER (in HEX)= 8(4.5-4=0.5,0.5*16=8)

DIVISION=4 / 16     RESULT  = 0     REMAINDER (in HEX)= 4
 Till Result becomes zero
**ANSWER H=48(hex)**
likewise for for all
finally,**Hello=48656c6c6f**